# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC - Writing array to range in Excel Add-In

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I have the following code in an Excel Add-In in C#:

```
long lngArrayLength = 14;
long lngArrayLength2 = array2.Length;

Excel.Range rngValues1 = (Excel.Range)wsNew.Cells[2, 1];
Excel.Range rngValues2 = (Excel.Range)wsNew.Cells[lngArrayLength2 + 1, lngArrayLength];
Excel.Range rngValues = wsNew.get_Range(rngValues1, rngValues2);

rngValues.Value = array2;
```

For reference, array2 has ten elements, each of which has 14 sub-elements. Example:

```
array2 = { (0, "a0", "b0", "c0"... "n0"), ... {9, "a9", "b9", "c9"... "n9) }
```

`rngValues` above is sized as `{[1..10,1..14]}`

Every time I try to run, I get the following error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I have ruled out:
1) File format, saving Book1 as .xlsx does not help
2) Reaching the column or row limit, does the same thing with thousands of elements or 10 of them
3) `[0]` vs `[1]` - indexed arrays and/or ranges, doesn't seem to matter/help

I am still having trouble debugging this... Is it possible this has something to do with the dimensions of the array vs the range?  How would I determine if that's the case or not?

UPDATE 1:

I created a loop that populates an array with data:

```
for (i = 1; i <= lngRows; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= lngCols; j++)
    {
        strTest[i-1, j-1] = "test (" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + ")";
    }
}
```

...and this works fine.

It now occurs to me that may of the elements in the array contain NULL values.

I'm thinking this may be the problem... Is it?

UPDATE 2:

Okay, so I now wrote a small routine to convert any NULLs to 0 (b/c the data type is `decimal?` (nullable decimal) and I guess I really need `decimal` instead:

```
public decimal replaceNullDec(decimal? decInput)
{
    if (decInput != null)
    {
        decimal rtn = (decimal)decInput;
        return rtn;
    }
    else
    {
        decimal rtn = 0;
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

So, now I have confirmed that all the NULLs are being replaced, but I'M STILL GETTING THE ERROR when writing the array to a range...

UPDATE 3:

Okay, so then I thought that maybe it's a data type issue, so I rewrote the code to convert all the elements in the array to strings instead before writing to the sheet.  I now get data, but instead of the actual values, I get text telling me the original TYPE (which in this case is a custom class called `Response`).

The interesting thing I noticed is that I'm getting 10 COLUMNS of text, and 4 COLUMNS of `#N/A`.

This makes me think that maybe I need to transpose the array?

Driving me crazy, but still trying.

Any help would be GREAT!

UPDATE 4:

Okay, I believe I'm getting closer.  In digging into how to transpose a 2d array in C#, I was getting some errors that lead me to believe I DON'T actually have a 2d array, but instead an "array of arrays" (which is what I thought a 2d array was, honestly) and it's probably the conversion of my `List` to `Array` using the `ToArray()` method that's an issue.

Here's that code:

```
object[] array2 = listAllData.ToArray();
```

So the next question becomes "how to convert a list to a 2d array?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

The issue came down to the fact that I was NOT writing a 2D array to the range, but instead I was building an array of `Response` objects and trying to write that to a range.

More details on the solution are found in this related post:
[How to Convert 2D List to 2D Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443171/how-to-convert-2d-list-to-2d-array-in-c-sharp)