# How to Convert 2D List to 2D Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following C# List:

```
List<Response> listAllData = new List<Response>();

listAllData.Add(new Response() {
    strId = propResponse.strId,
    strName = propResponse.strName
});
```

And then I am converting it to an array as such:

```
object[] array2 = listAllData.ToArray();
```

But when I'm trying to write data to a range using:

```
rngValues.Value = array2;
```

I'm getting an error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I am (reasonably) certain this is b/c the resulting `array2` is not actually a 2D multidimensional array, but instead an array-of-arrays.

So my question is... How do I get my `listAllData` into a 2D array?

It is not a "jagged array" meaning there are always 2 elements in each entry.

Comment: one question. how you are able to assign `listAllData.ToArray()` into object array. that would not even compile. (note you cant assign `Response[]` to `object[]` but an `object`. or you have to cast element by element.)

Comment: It's neither a 2d array or an array of arrays, it's 1d array of response objects

Comment: @Steve - yep, that's what i was missing... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> resulting array2 is not actually a 2D multidimensional array, but instead an array-of-arrays.

No, it's a 1-D array of *`Response` objects*. If you want it in a 2-D array of objects (where the row is the two string properties from the source object) you'll have to build a loop (Linq does not support 2-D arrays):

```
object[,] array2 = new object[listAllData.Count,2];
for(int i = 0; i < listAllData.Count; i++)
{
     array2[i,0] = listAllData[i].strId;
     array2[i,1] = listAllData[i].strName;
}
```